# MySQL PHPMyAdmin - Routine error

Tags: mysql

Using PHPMyAdmin and MySQL.
I'm trying to add a routine.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE cursor_ID INT;
  DECLARE cursor_VAL VARCHAR;
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR SELECT ca.apprentice_id, c.courseNumber, c.level FROM tblcourseassignments ca LEFT JOIN tblcourses c ON ca.course_id = c.id;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
  DECLARE varc1 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE varc2 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE varc3 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE gradeCount INT;

  OPEN cursor_i;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cursor_i INTO varc1, varc2;
    SELECT COUNT(id) INTO gradeCount FROM tblapprenticegrades WHERE apprentice_id = varc1 and course_id = varc2;

    if gradeCount = 0 then 
        INSERT INTO tblapprenticegrades(apprentice_id, course_id, phase) VALUES (varc1, varc2, varc3);
    end if

    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    --queries which couldnt be made into set based queries go here---
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor_i;
END;
```

But I keep on getting this error:

> MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '; DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE; DECLARE cursor_i
>   CURSOR FOR SELECT ca.ap' at line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the fixes done in your code.

1. Varchar needs length to be specified.
2. Cursor and handler declarations must at the end of the declarations
3. Small syntax errors.

---

```
BEGIN
DECLARE cursor_ID INT;
  DECLARE cursor_VAL VARCHAR(100);  /* Varchar length */
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE varc1 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE varc2 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE varc3 INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE gradeCount INT;
  /* cursor and handler declaration at the end of declarations */
  DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR SELECT ca.apprentice_id, c.courseNumber, c.`level` FROM tblcourseassignments ca LEFT JOIN tblcourses c ON ca.course_id = c.id;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cursor_i;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cursor_i INTO varc1, varc2;
    SELECT COUNT(id) INTO gradeCount FROM tblapprenticegrades WHERE apprentice_id = varc1 and course_id = varc2;

    if gradeCount = 0 then 
        INSERT INTO tblapprenticegrades(apprentice_id, course_id, phase) VALUES (varc1, varc2, varc3);
    end if;  /* semicolon here */

    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    --queries which couldnt be made into set based queries go here---
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor_i;
END
```